# Is it ok to have own property in react component?

Tags: reactjs

```
class VideoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.videoList = props.videos.map((video) => {
        return <VideoListItem video={video} />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul className="collection">
            {this.videoList}
        </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm just wondering if it's allowed to have my own property in react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have such a property but you need to keep in mind that when you store some value in such a property react will not re render a component - so if you are using that value in render, you might not see the updated value. With `setState` that's not the case. If you have something in state and then update the state react will re render the component.

There was some guideline on what to put in state (from Dan Abramov), short summary here:

- if you can calculate something from props, no need to put that data in state
- if you aren't using something in render method, no need to put that in state
- in other cases, you can store that data in state

Comment: Thanks for the guideline!! This guideline helps me a lot :)

Comment: Probably, what I'm setting to 'this.videoList' is something I can calculate from props, so it shouldnt be set to state.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is ok to have your own property in your react component. No one will blame you.

But don't forget to ship it with propType, it will save you lot time (catch bugs with type checking).

reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to having the `videoList` stored onto the Component instance?

You could store the list of videos on state, but it seems unecessary to do this and I would simplify `VideoList` to be a [stateless functional component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) that renders the list of videos passed in as a prop:

```
const VideoList = ({ videos }) => (
  <ul className="collection">
    {videos.map(video => <VideoListItem video={video} />)}
  </ul>
);
```

The official docs don't actually explain the syntax above, but it is basically syntactic sugar for a React component with no state, that just accepts `props`. The `({ videos })` syntax is [ES6 Destructuring](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-destructuring) in action. The `VideoList` component receives `props` and this syntax extracts `props.videos` as a variable on the component.

Additionally, as you're rendering a list of items, you should provide some kind of unique [key](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for each `VideoListItem` as you render it e.g.

```
<VideoListItem key={video.id} video={video} />
```